# Button @selector not working if button defined in NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, nsobject

I have the following problem: I am trying to define a button in an NSObject (in a separate file) and add it to my ViewController:

NSObject method:

in obj.h:

```
+(void)NewButtonInView:(UIView *)view withAction:(SEL)actionbutton;
```

in obj.m

```
+(void)NewButtonInView:(UIView *)view withAction:(SEL)actionbutton {

 UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
 [button addTarget:self action:actionbutton forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

in my ViewCotroller I import the obj.h and:

```
[obj NewButtonInView:[self view] withAction:@selector(actionB:)];
```

and:

```
-(void)actionB:(UIButton *)button {
 //some code
}
```

The button looks fine but when I click it I get the following error:
"[obj actionB:]: unrecognized selector sent to class"

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is this line

```
[button addTarget:self action:actionbutton forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

specifically, the use of `self`. You put the `actionB:` method in the viewController, but because the `NewButtonInView:withAction:` method is in a class method of `obj` self refers to the class `obj`. To fix it pass in the view controller as a parameter to the method like this

```
+(void)NewButtonInView:(UIView *)view withAction:(SEL)actionbutton target: (id) target {

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
[button addTarget: target action:actionbutton forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it worked. Although I a not sure why self refers to the NSObject as I added the button from the NSObject in my active view with [self view].

Comment: The target of the button isn't the view you put it in, it's whatever you tell it the target is. You told it the target was `self`, and at the moment you were calling the function, you were inside a class method of `obj`. That means you sent a message to `[obj class]`, and as the receiver, `[obj class]` *is* `self` for the scope of the function. Where the message came from is irrelevant -- all that matters is the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining it with a return value, as follows:

```
+(UIButton *)NewButtonInView:(UIView *)view withAction:(SEL)actionbutton withTarget:(id)target{

 UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50);
 [button addTarget:target action:actionbutton forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 return button;
}
```

Then when you call it:

```
UIButton *button = [obj NewButtonInView:[self view] withAction:@selector(actionB:) withTarget:self];
```

Not sure why you're doing it in an NSObject instead of in your view controller, but that's the way to go about it if you do.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It works. (I am really trying to create a custom keyboard to use in several projects - I've only written the relevant code here).